# How to delete few lines in a file that matches a specific pattern using perl script or command line?

Tags: linux, perl

Input file:

```
###
Hi 
I am Jack
I live in London
####
I am James
I live in Germany
####
```

Here I want to search for "Jack" and delete everything between the hashes.

Expected output:

```
###
I am James
I live in Germany
####
```

Comment: @PerlDuck the input was displayed in a broken way. That's not going to work.

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own? Where are you struggling?

Comment: @simbabque Why do you think it was broken? You now made three lines where we previously had only one line. You changed it to a different problem.

Comment: @PerlDuck I know I did. But the question says _delete everything between the **hashes**_. That tells me the `###` are part of the input. It's not clear if they are part of the input or not. My assumption makes more sense than the broken display though. I think the OP should [edit] to clarify. Voting to close.

Comment: hashes in specific count or not

Comment: @simbabque yeah I tried but it only deletes the lines below the matching pattern 
** sed '/Jack/,/^###/d' input > output **

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The secret is to use `$/` to define the "chunks" that you are looking for.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = '###';

while (<DATA>) {
  print unless /Jack/;
}

__DATA__
###
Hi 
I am Jack
I live in London
####
I am James
I live in Germany
####
```